# ConvertApi Web2Pdf missint content when mulitiple pages are concatenated

Tags: w3c, convertapi

I am using ConvertApi Web2Pdf for a wordpress site. When I use this tool [Web2Pdf Api Tool](http://www.convertapi.com/web-pdf-api) with a single url, the page converts properly with all content and styling, but when I concatenate several together with %20 I lose some of the content.

I have checked the pages at [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org)  and removed all errors, yet this didn't help. Has anyone else run into a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the api, had to switch apis.

Comment: How did you do it? Any hints?